# Sorting of lists on the basis of a particular element position

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have 3 lists:

```
a = [1, 4, 7]
b = [3, 9, 6]
c = [2, 5, 8]
```

and I want a final list which is:

```
d = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 9, 6]]
```

like sorting on the basis of the first element in the sub-array.

Comment: Why not just *try* to sort the list of lists and see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Use combine the three lists into a larger list, then sort the result:

```
d = sorted([a, b, c])
```

Lists are compared *lexicographically* when sorting, first elements first, and when those are equal, compare the second elements, etc.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 7]
>>> b = [3, 9, 6]
>>> c = [2, 5, 8]
>>> sorted([a, b, c])
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 9, 6]]
```

Comment: this gives me the output d=[[1,3,2],[4,9,5],[7,6,8]]
i dont want my initial lists to change